# Does Netty 5 support EventExecutorGroup with ThreadFactory?

Tags: netty, threadpool

In New and noteworthy in 5.0 (http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-5.0.html). "An implication of this change is that `NioEventLoop`, `NioEventLoopGroup`, `EpollEventLoop` and `EpollEventLoopGroup` do no longer take `ThreadFactory` objects as constructor arguments. The constructors of these classes have been updated to take `Executor` and `ExecutorFactory` objects instead."

In my use case, I have a handler handle blocking operation with an fixed size `EventExecutorGroup`.

```
EventExecutorGroup businessGroup = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(100);
pipeline.addLast(businessGroup, channelHandler);
```

To improve the performance in production, I want to use a `threadFactory` with dynamic size `threadPool`. So when traffic increase, the blocking handler could take more threads automatically. Does netty 5 support custom `EventExecurtorGroup` with `threadFactory`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean with your question, but netty 5 was designed to give you a lot more freedom, so you could use any type of executor you wanted (or create your own). `Executors.newCachedThreadPool();` is the default implementation of a threadpool that automatically scales the number of threads.

One thing you should note though is that 5.0 will not be supported for now. https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/4466